# Post data to database with form Haskell Yesod

Tags: html, forms, sqlite, haskell, yesod

I would like to know how to add new data to the database (sqlite) in Yesod. I have so far in models:

```
Payment
   timestamp UTCTime
   from UserId
   to UserId
   amount Int
```

And when the user is logged in he can go to his space where he can fill in a new form and send it to postPaymentsR:

```
 getUserR :: UserId -> Handler Html
 getUserR userId = do
    user <- runDB $ get404 userId
    mauth <- maybeAuthId
    case mauth of
       Just _ -> defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle $ toHtml $ userIdent user
        [whamlet|
            <h1> #{userIdent user}
            <form method=post action=@{PaymentsR}>
                <p>Enter new payment:
                <input type=text name=payment>
                <p>From user:
                <input type=text name=user>
                <input type=submit value="Add">
        |]      
       Nothing -> defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle $ toHtml $ userIdent user
        [whamlet|
            <h1> #{userIdent user}
        |]
```

And now I have to post this data into Payment. I have tried using runDB $ insert paymentTo UserIdent, and several other things but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You do know that Yesod has a built-in [form generator](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms), right?

Comment: That was even part of your required reading for this assignment.

Comment: The reason why I am not using a form generator is because the fields for From and To are UserId, and it wont accept something like userIdField, only textField

Comment: As this sounds like a homework project, I won't spell it out completely. But consider what you'd want the UI to look like for selecting a user. You'd probably want some kind of a way to *select* a *field* from a *list*.

Comment: If you still don't understand what @MichaelSnoyman said, I would like to refer you to the "Receipt.hs" file and look at the `ReceiptUserForm` function. Then search Yesod(-form) for functions which take a `OptionList a` as their argument.

Comment: Do you know where UserId is defined? Cant find it anywhere, I need it for form generation